# Nonlinear ODE for inverse CDF

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I have a CDF function of $F(x)=p = \int_{0}^{x} \mu e^{-\mu v}e^{-e^{\beta v}\lambda \alpha} dv$.

Using the theorem of calculus, taking derivative of the CDF with respect to $x$ will result to

$$ \frac{dp}{dx} = \mu e^{-\mu x}e^{-e^{\beta x}\lambda \alpha}  \rightarrow Equation.1$$

Second derivative of Eq.1 results to

$$ \frac{d^2p}{dx^2} = (\mu e^{-\mu x}e^{-e^{\beta x}\lambda \alpha})(-\mu-e^{\beta x}\beta \lambda \alpha) $$
$$ \frac{d^2p}{dx^2} = (\frac{dp}{dx})(-\mu-e^{\beta x}\beta \lambda \alpha) \rightarrow Equation.2$$

Using substitution of $u=\frac{dp}{dx}$, we can obtain $\frac{d^2p}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dp}.\frac{dp}{dx}=u \frac{du}{dp}$ which simplify Eq.2 into

$$ u \frac{du}{dp} = (u)(-\mu-e^{\beta x}\beta \lambda \alpha) $$ but we still have $x$ term in the equation. Is there alternative way that I can do so that I can solve the CDF before use the solution to invert it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe the integral is related to the same problem mentioned in [exponential integral problem](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-particular-integral-of-e-e-x-in-ordinary-differential-equations). Thus, is there any numerical methods that I can use to approximate the inverse of the CDF?

Comment: As you pointed yourself the substitution does not work because of the $x$-term. In fact it only works for autonomous ODEs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more whats your actual question? It seems to me you are generating an ODE from a solution and then try to solve the ODE. This will just give you back the initial $p$ you started with, right?

Comment: Yes sure, actually I'm trying to find the quantile function (inverse CDF) of my CDF by borrowing the idea of using ODE from the work of [quantile mechanics] (http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahwts/lgsnotes/EJAM_Quantiles.pdf). The only different is that the strategy for quantile mechanic is applied to the non-closed formula of quantile function (for instance, the inverse CDF of normal). However for my case, I still don't have a quantile formula to begin with.